# How to use VLOOKUP in this situation

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am looking to use VLOOKUP to find the operatives names that require Irata Training

[image]

^ Is the sheet I am using

I'm not sure if its possible as the Irata training has two levels

Comment: How about filtering on column D on cells that contain "Irata" and copy/paste the operator list wherever you need them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of all employees in another table, and want to do a lookup to find out what (if any) Irata training they require, the following array formula will work:

Assuming you start your Irata table with Jose Castillo in cell H2:

```
=vlookup(H2,IF((D$4:D$28="Irata Level 1"+(E$4:E$9="Irata Level 2")=1,C$4:D$28,""),2,FALSE)
```

then enter the formula by holding Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it an array formula.

This will return #N/A for employees who don't require Irata training - if you would prefer to see some text instead you can use:

```
=iferror(vlookup(H2,IF((D$4:D$28="Irata Level 1"+(E$4:E$9="Irata Level 2")=1,C$4:D$28,""),2,FALSE),"Not Required")
```

and use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter the formula - this will return Not Required next to Charlyn Baren